# Magento - Matching URL Request path with URL Key

Tags: php, magento, url

I'm trying to match all the URL Request path with the URL key of the products
I often used duplicates for adding new products since most of the attributes are the same, the problem is, no matter how many times i changed the URL key, the request path will follow the duplicated product request path/URL Key with an addition of the current product ID, i.e:

Product ID: 10023;

name: Sweet Apple; URL key: sweet-apple; Request Path: sweet-apple.html

Product ID: 10024 (Duplicate of product 10023);

name: Sour Orange; URL key: sour-orange; Request Path: sweet-apple10024.html

Product ID: 10025 (Duplicate of product 10024);

name: Sweet Orange; URL key: sweet-orange; Request Path: sweet-apple10025.html

I'm aware that I can change them manually but currently, I have around 20k products and it's impossible for me to change them all manually. So again, is there any way I can match the request path with the url key?

Comment: Your products' url_key attribute's may differ, but it seems theri url_path attributes are same, resulting url rewrite module to differantiate them adding product id's in the end. Reindex may resolve this, but check their url_key and url_path attribute values in catalog_product_entity_varchar.